# Why does Django give me an invalid filter error when I try to apply two filters?

Tags: django, jinja2

I want to make two changes to the text that is displayed in my Django template. First, I want to strip the text of any HTML. The following code works for me:

```
{{ article.abstract|striptags }}
```

Second, I want to replace all instances of `\n` with `&lt;br /&gt;` I tried:

```
{{ article.abstract|striptags|replace('\n', '&lt;br /&gt;')  }}
```

That gave me an invalid filter error. I even tried:

```
{{ article.abstract|striptags|replace('\n', '')  }}
```

That did not work either. Are there any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem (removing html from output), `striptags` is a good choice.

For your second problem (converting `\n` to newlines), check out the [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter. Actually, in your case, [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) might be a better choice.

Your code would look like this:

```
{{ article.abstract|striptags|linebreaksbr }}
```

Comment: Thank you. I still see many "\n\n". Could it be that "linebreaksbr" only filters out newlines when they are separated by spaces?

Comment: Is it necessary to import it somewhere or add additional code because even the following does not work: {{ "foo\nbar"|linebreaksbr }}?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. linebreaksbr only works if the text is: /n. In my case, the text was appearing as /n, but the first character was being escaped so in reality it was //n. The solution was just to make a custom tag. Thanks for your help though.